# Most effective implementation of repeating browser automation in the same session

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, apache-poi

Equipped with little technical knowledge I started to implement browser automation using Selenium Webdriver in Java. I am also using Apache POI to read data from an excel file. I have been able to achieve what I desired but there is a problem. What I set out to do was have an excel sheet with one column and 'n' number of rows, each of these cells would be a 10 digit number. Using selenium Webdriver I was able to login to a website pick up each of these numbers one cell at a time from Excel, fill in the form in the website and generate the desired output. My problem is when I pick the second number instead of just going back to the homepage and re-entering the number and repeating the task, a new browser is opened, followed by logging in and so on. I googled to find a solution to this problem and a lot of the times JUnit was mentioned. What I would like to know is if JUnit is the only solution? Since my knowledge in Java is fairly limited is there a utility in Java that can help me in achieving this or any other better solution that I may not be aware of?

Thank you and sorry for the long post.

```
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    int[][] data;
    data = excelRead();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        formfill(data[i][0]);

    }
public static void formfill(int number) throws Exception {

    WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();
    wd.get("URL");
    // wd.get("Login Page")).click();
    wd.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).sendKeys("username");
    wd.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).sendKeys("password");
    wd.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();

    wd.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).sendKeys(String.valueOf(number));

            Set<String> windowId = wd.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> itererator = windowId.iterator();
    String mainWinID = itererator.next();
    String newAdwinID = itererator.next();
    wd.switchTo().window(newAdwinID);
    wd.switchTo().window(mainWinID);
    wd.findElement(By.xpath(xpath to go back to homepage again to enter the next number)).click();
}
public static int[][] excelRead() throws Exception {
    File excel = new File("C:\\testing.xls");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
    HSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
    int rowNum = ws.getLastRowNum()+1;
    int colNum = ws.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
    int[][] data = new int[rowNum][colNum];

    for (int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {

        HSSFRow row = ws.getRow(i);

        for (int j = 0; j < colNum; j++) {
            HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);
            int value = cellToString(cell);
            data[i][j] = value;
        }
    }
    return data;
}
public static int cellToString(HSSFCell cell) {

    int type;
    Object result;

    type = cell.getCellType();
    switch (type) {
    case 0: // numeric value in excel
        result = cell.getNumericCellValue();
        break;
    case 1: // String value in excel
        result = cell.getStringCellValue();
        break;
    default:
        throw new RuntimeException("There are no support for this type of cell");
    }
    double z = (double) result;
    int y = (int) z;
    return y;
}
```

}

Comment: You should show the important parts of your code.

Comment: You're probably creating a new `WebDriver` object for each task, to use the same browser instance you can navigate back to the home page by using the [get(...)](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#get-java.lang.String-) method.

Comment: I have added important parts of the code

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new FireFox browser instance every time you call the `formfill(...)` method, that is because of this line:

```
 WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();
```

to reuse the same browser instance, you could create only one instance of `FirefoxDriver`, for example:

```
public class test {
    WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();
    ......
    public static void formfill(int number) throws Exception {
         wd.get(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming that to work it would still make me go to the login page, enter username and password and hit login for each number. I was trying to think of a solution where I login once and fill the form again and again using different numbers.

Comment: @user3777207 You can separate this process in 2 methods. One to login and the other one to submit the form. The idea is to reuse the `WebDriver` object so you won't open a new browser instance.

Comment: If this answered your question, please make sure you accept it as the answer. Thanks!